# where i can find the ItemStyle.xsl?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, item-styles, style-library

I want to edit `ItemStyle` to make some changes but the problem is that i cannot see it, I don't know whether it is hidden or unable to edit.

I am pretty sure that `ItemsStyle` could be found at `Style Library`  but it's now shown in it as shown in this image:

[image]

But I cannot find it. Please help me!

Comment: make sure your site is a publishing site and you already opened the root site, not the subsite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the `ItemStyle` is located in `Style Library` at the Root site collection. but you should be aware of

1. The `ItemStyle` is located at the top level site collection (not subsite) specifically at `Style Library > XSL Style Sheets`. So make sure that the current site that you have already opened via SharePoint Designer is the Root site, not a subsite.
2. The `ItemStyle` is related to Content Query web part that requires `Publishing site template` to use it.